# How to pass multiple values to a API call in get method?

Tags: python, list, api

This is my list:

```
unique_IMO = [94229,95986,96967,94731,95731,96612]
```

I need to pass these numbers to the following request:

```
url = 'https://api.lloydslistintelligence.com/v1/aispositionhistory?output=json&vesselImo={0}&pageNumber={1}'.format(unique_IMO,1)
```

I was able to call the endpoint for each number using a for loop but I don't know how to pass all the numbers at once.

I tried the below code but it still gave an error.

```
test1 = format(','.join(map(str,unique_IMO)))
```

Can someone please help me with this?

I have a list of numbers which I am trying to pass all at once to an API call. I did check using Postman to see if the endpoint accepts multiple values and it does.
[API documentation snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYtDI.png)

So below is what I'm doing right now and it works. I am trying to make the api calls faster/efficient.

```
df_list = []
for ind,row in vessels.iterrows():   
    vesselImo = int(row['Imo'])

     


    #Retrieve data from aispositionhistory endpoint          

    vessel_hist = pd.DataFrame()
    total_recs = 0

    for date_string in date_list:
        url = 'https://api.lloydslistintelligence.com/v1/aispositionhistory?output=json&vesselImo={0}&dateRange={1}&pageNumber={2}'.format(vesselImo,date_string,1)
        head = {'Authorization': '{}'.format(api_token)}
        response = requests.get(url, headers=head)

        #****DEBUGGING****
        #print("status code: ", response.status_code )

        if(response.json()['Data']['totalRecords'] != 0):
            tmp = response.json()['Data']['items']
            df = json_normalize(tmp)
            vessel_hist = vessel_hist.append(df,ignore_index=True)


        #Get reported number of records for validation
        total_recs = total_recs + response.json()['Data']['totalRecords']

        #Identify if API response is multiple pages
        if(response.json()['Data']['totalPages'] > 1):
            num_pages = response.json()['Data']['totalPages']
            #print('API pull had more than one page: ' + date_string)

            for page_no in range(2,num_pages+1):
                url = 'https://api.lloydslistintelligence.com/v1/aispositionhistory?output=json&vesselImo={0}&dateRange={1}&pageNumber={2}'.format(vesselImo,date_string,1)
                response = requests.get(url, headers=head)
                tmp = response.json()['Data']['items']
                df = json_normalize(tmp)
                vessel_hist = vessel_hist.append(df,ignore_index=True)



    # Validation based on record count
    if(total_recs != vessel_hist.shape[0]):
        print('Validation Error: reported records do not match dataframe')

    if(vessel_hist.shape[0]>0):
        #Format Dataframe       
        new_columns = ['vesselId','MMSI','PositionTimestamp','Latitude','Longitude','Speed','Course','Rot','Heading',
               'nearestPlace','nearestPlaceId','nearestCountry','Distance','Destination','Eta','Draught',
               'Dimensions','Status','Ship_type','Source']

        vessel_hist.columns = new_columns

        vessel_hist = vessel_hist[['MMSI','PositionTimestamp','Status','Latitude','Longitude','Speed','Course','Rot',
                                  'Heading','Draught','Destination','Eta','Source','Ship_type','Dimensions',
                                   'Distance','nearestCountry','nearestPlace','nearestPlaceId','vesselId']]

        vessel_hist['PositionTimestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(vessel_hist['PositionTimestamp'],dayfirst=False)
        vessel_hist.sort_values('PositionTimestamp', inplace=True)
        vessel_hist.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

        df_list.append(vessel_hist)

    print('Input vessel Id: ' + str(vesselImo))
    print('Input Date Range: ' + start_input + ' - ' + end_input)        
    print('No. of AIS records: ' + str(vessel_hist.shape[0]))

df_list
```

vessels is a dataframe which contains the IMO numbers

```
vessels = pd.DataFrame((94229,95986,96967,94731,95731,96612),columns=['Imo'])
```

date_list is a list created based on the desired time range.

Comment: Hi! Can you share how the endpoint expects to receive multiple IMO?
By the way, if you're using python >= 3.6 you can use f-string instead of format
```a_list = [1, 2, 3];
a_string = ",". join(map(str, a_list));
the_url = f"https://www.something.com/param={a_string}";
print(the_url)```

Comment: Thank you for responding. The endpoint expects to receive the numbers like this: 94229,95986,96967. I tried using f-string but it's not giving me the entire output.

Comment: Your `test1` code should work if that's what it expects.

Comment: Do you have a link to the API documentation?

Comment: I only have the pdf for the documentation. `test1` didn't work. It gives a string output while the API expects numbers.

Comment: Can you paste an image of the pdf where there is this request? Check if there are other get requests in the doc. Check if the 4snok answer works for you. You might have to convert the list to string in that example.

Comment: @angelacpd I've attached an image of the documentation. Hope that helps

Comment: @angelacpd your code does work. The endpoint takes only 1 day at a time while providing multiple IMO's and I was giving a month as date range.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I was giving the date range wrong. @angelacpd solution works

Answer (score 0):

Hope this example will help

```py
import requests


def main():

    unique_IMO = [94229, 95986, 96967, 94731, 95731, 96612]

    base_url = "http://httpbin.org"
    query_params = {
        "output": "json",
        "vesselImo": unique_IMO,
        "pagerNumber": 1
        }
    
    response = requests.get(url=base_url + "/get", params=query_params)
    print(response.json())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

GET query parameters will be:

````
{'args': {'output': 'json', 'pagerNumber': '1', 'vesselImo': ['94229', '95986', '96967', '94731', '95731', '96612']}, 'headers': {'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Host': 'httpbin.org', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.27.1', 'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': 'Root=1-633bc95b-2771014e17fa5dc6580e4e3e'}, 'origin': 'x.x.x.x', 'url': 'http://httpbin.org/get?output=json&vesselImo=94229&vesselImo=95986&vesselImo=96967&vesselImo=94731&vesselImo=95731&vesselImo=96612&pagerNumber=1'}```
````

Comment: Thank you! It didn't work. Please see my postman api call snippet below                                          `https://api.lloydslistintelligence.com/v1/aispositionhistory?vesselImo=9422938,9598660,9696759,9696747,9473183,9573103,9675951,9599157,9331464,9658874,9661223,9588495,9422940,9588483,9661211,9445966,9397731,9539602,9476848,9493535,9324992,9335989,9600645,9563677,9671931,9743265,9286968,9518086,9405332,9461130,9658886&output=json` .

Comment: I've also edited my question with the code I'm using right now